# How do I deal with low loadings in the first principal component of PCA?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a matrix data consist of 40 variables (year data) with 1500 obs. I used this code:

```r
jjas <- df
pca.jjas <- prcomp (jjas, center = T, scale =T)
```

Here are the results both variance explained and loadings.

```r
head(expl.var)
 # [1] 86  6  2  1   1  1

pca.jjas$rotation

#   PC1  PC2
# y1981  -0.1628  0.092
# y1982  -0.1668  4.24E-05
# y1983  -0.1613  -0.0442
```

All of loadings value less than |0.3|. My problems seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53637289/low-pca-loadings-especially-on-pc1-and-most-others). Here are my questions:

a. Since variance explained high in the first 2 principal component (accounts for 92%), why loadings so low? How do I deal with the results?

b. If raw data were converted to another distribution like Log Normal Distribution, could the result will be different?

Comment: Can you explain the output `pca.jjas$rotation` a bit more? It looks like PC1 contains years?

Comment: What is the meaning of the threshold of 0.3?  The only universal threshold that applies is the maximum size of a loading must be at least $\sqrt{1/40}\approx 0.158.$  What do you mean by "deal with" this??

Comment: @frank, output of pca.jjas$are for PC1: -0.1628, -0.1668, and -0.1613. Seems I wrote wrong results.

Comment: @whuber: Thanks for the information, I though loadings must at least 0.30 based on correlation coefficient but the problem rise when interpret the results. From PC1 for example, more than 70% variable has same loadings valued as shown above. How I "deal", because I have conducted dataset contains of time series; where variables are time (years-y1981 denote as year 1981) and row as observations.